# How to get Token authorization using the Retrofit2 request?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to make a POST request to the server using Retrofit 2 and get an authorization token for further work with the server.
response code = 400 ...
login and passwod are stored in the Login class.
Here is the server authentication method:

[image]

My MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val bulder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://tv-server.trinity-tv.net/server/TvServerService/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

    val retrofit: Retrofit = bulder.build()
    val userClient: UserClient = retrofit.create(UserClient::class.java)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        login_btn.setOnClickListener { login() }
    }

    private fun login() {
        val login = Login("1", "2")
        val call: Call<User> = userClient.getLogin(login)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<User> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
                response.code()
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, response.body()?.token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

My interface :

```
interface UserClient {

    @POST("Auth")
    fun getLogin(@Body login: Login) : Call<User>
}
```

Comment: Actually you already got token: `response.body()?.token`.
So unclear what do you want.

Comment: do you mean you want to use this token for further request?

Comment: ander, I can't get the token because my response.code () is equal to code 400 (the request syntax is not correct)

Comment: Do you want to generate Token from app then se this https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit